Cannot use `execute-actions-email` API in Keycloak non-master realm
In Keycloak 21.1, I was able to send the execute-actions-email request for the master realm users using the following endpoint:
curl --location --request PUT 'http://<your_ip>:<your_port>/auth/admin/realms/master/users/<user_id>/execute-actions-email' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer <my_token>' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '["UPDATE_PASSWORD"]'

And you'll get a 204 response (the server successfully processed the request, but is not returning any content) which is fine.
The problem is, I was not able to do this for non-master realms. Despite having assigned the necessary roles to my client and user, I get a 400 Bad Request response.
{
    "errorMessage": "Client is not enabled"
}


I am 100% sure I have enabled both the client and the user.
The SMTP configuration of the realm works because I can send test emails using the Keycloak admin panel.
Using a token obtained from the master realm returns the same response in this non-master realm; but works fine in the master realm. I thought master realm tokens can be used to alter other realms (and it is true for other actions).

Do you have any ideas?

The question is tagged with MongoDB Realm, the database. Can you update the question as to how Realm ties in?

@Jay I removed the 'realm' tag as it caused misunderstanding. I meant the Keycloak realms (non-master realms). So it has nothing to do with MongoDB terminology.
